# Excel Graph Display Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have been attempting to create a line chart where my month data is on the left and my name is on the bottom, and for the graph data labels are added to show the count for the past 90 minutes and I can NOT get it right!  Can someone show me how to achieve this result before I go completely bald by ripping out the remainder of my hair?

Image to show data

[image: Data Image]

And I need the data to display:

> Graph where Month is on left side
>   Name is on bottom
>   And data labels are added to show Count on the month basis

Comment: Are you looking for a graph with every name on the bottom, or just yours (as you stated in the question)? Do you want one graph with everyone on it, or multiple individual graphs?

Comment: @jrichall - One graph with everyone name spanning across the bottom

Comment: You might be better served with a bar chart. I don't know if you can attain what you're hoping to with a line. If the names are at the bottom, a line chart is going to want to sort by name. So, "James" would have to have every month's numbers above him, a line chart can't just climb upwards on the Y axis; it needs to move across the X axis (unless someone knows otherwise.) I'll tinker with it though.

Comment: @jrichall A line chart will not try to sort by name. If the X values are dates, it will sort by date.

Comment: Your question makes perfect sense until _"the graph data labels are added to show the count for the past 90 minutes"_. Could you explain what that means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't upload images to imagur at work without going through an answer, I'll leave these here:

While you could have the names at the bottom with a line graph, in my opinion it's a bit difficult to read. You wouldn't be able to have the Month on the Y axis though, since "James" would need points at 5, 12, 18, 6. The line would be straight up and down, and the plot points would not be feasible. This was the closest I could get:
[image]

However, if you want to show Monthly Numbers, sorted by person, a bar chart is super easy to read:
[image]

You still can't really "sort" by month on the Y axis, because you'd have gaps in the data.

If you're able to upload an example of the chart you're trying to create, I can continue to help.